# "Unknown format for file %s" in Obspy.core read

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a segy file with obspy.core but it seems it cannot read segy files, also if in the documentation segy files are supported.

My code:

```
from obspy.core import read
st = read(f1, unpack_trace_headers=True)
```

it leads to this error message:

```
TypeError: Unknown format for file myfile.segy
```

So I tried to specify the format:

```
st = read(f1, format='segy', unpack_trace_headers=True)
```

And this is the error I got:

```
TypeError: Format "SEGY" is not supported. Supported types:
```

After "Supported types: " there is.....nothing!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem uninstalling obspy with

```
pip uninstall obspy
```

and installing it as explained at this link:
https://github.com/obspy/obspy/wiki/Installation-via-Anaconda

Answer (score 1):

sorry for late response:

Obspy can read segy files

```
from obspy.io.segy.core import _read_segy

stream = _read_segy('segy_file', unpack_trace_headers = True)

#plot first trace
stream[0].plot()

# see all traces in the segy file
stream.traces

# find all trace headers
stream[0].stats.segy.trace_header
```

unpack is used to unpack all trace headers from segy trace headers

[Find here further details](https://docs.obspy.org/master/packages/obspy.io.segy.html)